# Android tap on device body sensor

Tags: android, android-sensors

following the [KnockToUnlock](http://www.knocktounlock.com/) Iphone app video,
I was wondering what would be the best sensor to utilize for detecting tapping on a device body?

Also what would be it's sensitivity? i.e , can i detect a tap on the side of the device and a tap on the back of a device?

Answer (score 0):

Well the only sensor capable of detecting taps would be the accelerometer. However you will need to have the device on in order for the sensor to detect the tap. When the screen goes off usually the sensor is also turned off (I remember there being some exceptions, some HTC phones I think).

The accelerometer does detect acceleration on 3 axis so in theory it should be possible to detect on which side of the device the tap was made.

I have seen code on Android used to wake up a device when it was tapped on, however the devices is not completely turned off due to the reasons stated above.

Accelerometer tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSensor/article.html#accelerometer